# Best practices for writing Blu-Ray discs on Linux

Tags: iso, blu-ray

I recently bought a Blu-Ray writer and am wondering how to best write the discs. The scenario is: I have a directory full of files and want to put them on the disc, read them back once to verify, and then put the disc on a shelf (i.e., the main purpose is for backup). Some of the files are bigger than 4.4GB or whatever the limit is for ISO filesystems.

For writing to DVDs, I currently use `growisofs`, with `split` to break the files into bite-size chunks. growisofs doesn't seem to have good UDF support and splitting the files is lame, which is the motivation for my question.

What is the current best practice for writing files onto a BD-R disc?

I am on Debian Wheezy (Testing).

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/1620197/udf-formatting-a-bd-re-under-linux-media-type-bdr-unknown

Answer (score 3):

I ended up creating a zero file with dd, making a UDF filesystem on that with mkudffs, loop-mounting it, populating it, and then writing the UDF image with growisofs -Z /dev/dvd=foo.udf. Whether that's a best practice, I can't say, but it's a bit roundabout. On the other hand it does work.

Packet writing led to much sadness and doesn't seem to work on DVD+R, which I also want to write using the same process.

Comment: Thanks for this. It still seems to be the best way to do this. Sad but true.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully used [udftools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-udf/) to write *DVDs* with larger than 4GB files. In theory it supports Blu-ray writing but I lack the necessary hardware to test it.

I recommend using a graphical application like [k3b](http://www.k3b.org/) if you can. It's not an option for servers without monitors and automated backup scripts but for causal use it is more convinient.

Comment: Why K3b? Does it work better than it's competitors?

Comment: The main issue with k3b is that it uses growisofs' crufty UDF support.

Comment: @Tshepang: No reason. It's an example of an easy method any of the similar programs should work.