# Archiving files on Linux using Pioneer BDR-XD07B Blu-ray burner

Tags: fedora, mkisofs, blu-ray

I'm using Fedora v32. The only support I could find for Blu-ray burners on Linux is either `xfburn` or `growisofs`. I'd like to add files for backup and then burn it. When I tried using `xfburn` and selecting "Pioneer BDR-XD07B" under "Burning device", after adding the files to be saved, I get:

> Failed to unmount 'Blank DS-R Disc'. Drive cannot be used for burning.

Couldn't find an example of `growisofs` adding files to be burned then burning the disc. I assume I'll need to use `mkisofs` to make an ISO file with the data files in it then burning the Blu-ray disc with that ISO?

I looked for Linux drivers for the Pioneer BDR-XD07B but found only
Windows and MacOS drivers.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you use cdrecord/mkisofs? cdrecord supports Bluray since 2007 - it is the first OSS program to support Bluray.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practices for writing Blu-Ray discs on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9562/best-practices-for-writing-blu-ray-discs-on-linux)

Answer (score 3):

assuming that your drive is represented as `/dev/sr0` and that you
want to put a copy of directory `/home/thomas/projects` onto a blank
or appendable medium as `/projects` you could do:

```
xorriso -for_backup -dev /dev/sr0 -map /home/thomas/projects /projects
```

More `-map source target` commands can be added to this run.
The medium will stay appendable (unless it is a DVD-R DL or a fastly
blanked DVD-RW). So you could do more of these runs later.

Checkread all backup sessions and compare with the recorded MD5 sums by:

```
xorriso -for_backup -indev /dev/sr0 -check_media --
```

or the most recent session by

```
xorriso -for_backup -indev /dev/sr0 -check_md5 FAILURE --
```

My own backups are done like in the example
"Incremental backup of a few directory trees" in
https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/man_1_xorriso.html#EXAMPLES

```
xorriso \
  -abort_on FATAL \
  -for_backup -disk_dev_ino on \
  -assert_volid 'PROJECTS_MAIL_*' FATAL \
  -dev /dev/sr0 \
  -volid PROJECTS_MAIL_"$(date '+%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S')" \
  -not_leaf '*.o' -not_leaf '*.swp' \
  -update_r /home/thomas/projects /projects \
  -update_r /home/thomas/personal_mail /personal_mail \
  -commit -toc -check_md5 FAILURE -- -eject all
```

I mainly use BD-R, BD-RE, and DVD+RW media.
Be aware that many drives restrict BD-R to 128 sessions.
(But not ASUS BW-16D1HT with firmware revision 1.01. It does more than 255
sessions on BD-R.)

Have a nice day :)

Thomas

Comment: This program dies not support the UDF filesystem that is the official standard for BluRay media.

Comment: UDF is a prescription for Blu-ray video. The SCSI/MMC specs do not prescribe any particular filesystem type for general data storage.

Comment: Well, ` mkisofs` supports UDF, so there is no need to use an outdated filesystem.

Comment: Where to find information on specific drive BD-R session number limitations?  Could not find it for Pioneer.

Comment: Gnome's Nautilus required ejecting the drive in order to see the written files.